# Как сжать и разбить папку с логами на части?

Tags: linux

Крон-скрипт должен периодически отсылать на почту логи сервера. Иногда этих логов оказывается столько, что даже в архивированном виде они не помещаются в почтовое вложение. Поэтому нужно папку с логами сжать и разбить на части. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сжатие и разбиение - командами tar + split:

```
tar -cj logs/ | split -d -b 1M - logs.tar.bz2.
```

На выходе будут файлы: `logs.tar.bz2.00`, `logs.tar.bz2.01`... Восстановление папки - командами cat + tar:

```
cat logs.tar.bz2.* | tar -xj
```

Answer (score 0):

Разбиение архива tar на лету (архив не будет создаваться):

```bash
tar cz /path/to/source/folder | split -b 10M
```

Восстановление архива из частей и распаковка:

- Восстановить архив из частей:

```bash
cat * > archive.tar
```

- Собрать архив из частей и сразу распаковать (сам файл архива создан не будет):

```bash
cat * | tar xz
```

[Использование архиватора tar, ключи, разбиение архива на части](http://valerij.pp.ua/tar-uses-keys-split/)

Comment: Эм.. А `cat *` порядок файлов гарантирует?